# Count X records matching certain conditions and only where there is a corresponding Y record

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for some help with a formula. On my 'data' sheet, I have data in the format below:

```
   A         B            C            D            E          F        G           H           I          J
1 UID   RecordType      HCode     AdmittedDate   Forename   Surname    DOB          Sex      STDate      RDate
2 87962 STAsses         STIV1     01/01/2012     Mark       Jones      13/07/1978   Male     09/12/2012 
3 89658 Transfer        GLSI2     01/01/2012     Alison     Aitken     20/12/1956   Female               08/07/2013 
4 84563 Discharge       JHOP1     01/01/2012     David      Beckham    09/08/1987   Male                 08/07/2013
5 89654 STAsses         STGE1     01/01/2012     Andrew     Macbeth    27/09/1976   Male     08/07/2012 
6 89867 Transfer        KIND1     01/01/2012     George     Deas       08/05/1989   Male                 08/07/2013
7 87962 Transfer        STIV1     01/01/2012     Mark       Jones      13/07/1978   Male                 04/03/2013 
8 89654 Transfer        STGE1     01/01/2012     Andrew     Macbeth    27/09/1976   Male                 12/08/2012
```

On my 'report' sheet, I have the following table set up:

```
      B             C             D          E         F
4 HospCode     RecordType      Jul-12     Aug-12    Sep-12
5 STGE1        Assessments
6              Transfers
7              Discharges
8
```

What I need is a formula in cell D6 of the 'report' sheet, which counts all 'Transfer' records from the 'data' sheet, occurring in the month specified in D4 and with an 'HCode' matching that in B5 of the 'report' sheet. The tricky part is that I need this formula only to count records which have a corresponding 'STAssess' record.

Might be pushing the limits of Excel here, but anything is possible!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B1:B8, "Transfer", Sheet1!C1:C8, Sheet2!B5)
```

This is an example with 2 criteria, you can add a lot many more for multiple IFS and COUNTIFS will count those.

---

In case of finding multiple criteria across rows, you are better off making a Pivot Table out of this data range and then doing multiple selections thereof.

If you would like to accomplish this via formula, there is a two-step process.

THe formula described above needs to be placed next to each Person's name in Sheet1 as an additional column. And then run another COUNTIFS on this column and Column B counting that there is >1 Count for the person existing... and counting if the STAssess criterion is fulfilled or not.

Comment: Thanks. I have already got this far using a similar formula. However, I need to only count 'Transfer' records where there is a corresponding 'STAssess' record. The unique field is 'UID' in column A.

Comment: I haven't yet tested this. Will report back tomorrow and mark as answered if so. Thanks!